# Separate two images joined using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I can merge two images using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`.

Can I do a reverse process? Means can I have those two separate images back?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using CGImageCreateWithImageInRect method.
Since you merged the images, you should know the subregion you need when you are trying to separate or un-merge.

Pass in the CGImage as the first parameter for the image you are trying to separate and CGRect as the second parameter.

```
CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(originalImage.CGImage, cropRect);
```

[Apple doc for CGImageCreateWithImageInRect](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1454683-cgimagecreatewithimageinrect)